# How to configure lightning dialer

Tags: lightning, administration

My Organization Edition is '**Professional Edition**'. I am a **system-admin**. The org need to enable the lightning dialer. Search in **setup** with dialer word show me **nothing**.

What should I do?

- Will I need to install any package from appexchange.
- Will call-center configuration help me to make a call from the sales cloud to the client phone(How to configure call center?).

Comment: Do you have Dialer permissions and provision Dialer licenses enabled for your organization?

Comment: @Swetha Setup==> permission set has no permission for Dialer. Will I need to create it?

Comment: Before that can you confirm if Dialer licenses are avaialble in your org: In Setup, enter Company Information in the Quick Find box, then select Company Information, and check for Dialer Outbound User and Dialer Inbound User under Permission Set Licenses.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.voice_impl_prereqs.htm&type=5),

> Before beginning the implementation process, Salesforce must enable Dialer permissions and provision Dialer licenses for your organization.

> Your Salesforce contact coordinates it with you, but you can check if your organization has available Dialer licenses.
> In Setup, enter Company Information in the Quick Find box, then select Company Information, and check for Dialer Outbound User and Dialer Inbound User under Permission Set Licenses.

In case you do not have these, the best course of action is to communicate with your Account Team regarding the provisioning of Licenses.